# How determine that app start as Linux daemon

Tags: c#, linux, daemon, core

I have console app that would start as console and as Linux daemon.

How can I determine that app started as Linux daemon (not console)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend passing an extra command line parameter when you start as Linux daemon and checking for the existence of that extra command line parameter in your code.

Comment: yes, I thought about this version. But I wanted to know if there is a standard functional for this.

Comment: You could use Process.Start() to run "ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?" to find all daemon processes on Linux (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175380/how-to-list-all-running-daemons) and then see if your currently running process is in this list.